# Playing Video in DirectX (WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, video, directx

I have a WPF 4/VB.net project, and I'm trying to play video in it. I've been using a mediaelement, much to the chagrin of the program's overall performance. Thus, I'm looking into the only other viable alternative that I can find for my project...directx.

Which brings me to my question. Is it possible to play video (either Theora [.ogv] or Flash Video [.flv]) in DirectX? If so, how?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mediaelements Performance is not so bad and dependent on Codec. Mediaelement can also Play all Formats if you have required Codecs installed.

I have a DirectX Video Player written in VB.Net (without WPF).I used the DirectX SDK. But the methods are highly error prone.

To play your Videoformats, you can install a Codec-Pack e.g. K-Lite with FFDshow (highly recommended)